# Custom duplicate-answer flag marked "helpful," but no action taken

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-answer, helpful-flags

(There are lots of questions about flags having been marked helpful but not acted on, so I at least understand the mechanism that can cause this circumstance; however, each existing question seems pretty circumstance-specific, so I think it's worthwhile to ask one about my particular circumstance.)

I'm not sure how to link directly to my review, so I'll quote it: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974579/1858225) "appears to be a straight copy of Ajinkya's answer with a few additional rows (at the time it was copied, Ajinkya's answer didn't have entries for Win. Server 2012 R2 or Win. 8.1)." Note that Ajinkya's answer is the accepted answer; the answers are currently identical.

I would say that this appears to be a blatant attempt to get rep by copying someone else's answer, but the user who posted it has only ever posted this one answer, for which they garnered a measly 18 points (the -2 is from me; I apparently didn't downvote when I initially submitted the flag, but upon discovering that the flag had been marked "helpful" but wasn't acted on, I guess I was irritated enough to downvote).

That said, copying answers verbatim still seems like bad practice, and I still think the answer should be deleted. Does anyone disagree?

Comment: The user posting that answer was probably just some random visitor that found the table helpful but out-of-date, and was not aware of the mechanisms in place for editing and commenting (and the intentional restrictions of those mechanisms for users with lower rep). So I don't think there was any malicious intent here. That said, the answer should probably be deleted, but there could be a point made that the accepted answer should attribute the author of the additional lines from the duplicate answer as well. (That last sentence sounds terribly confusing when I read it out loud)

Comment: @HugoRune Nah, it made sense, I think. Attribution seems laudable, but...for a random auto-named visitor who has never returned to the site, and whose answer should have been an edit? "Thanks to userXXX, whose answer is identical to mine" sounds more confusing than helpful.